# Как правильно пробросить между компонентами функционал?

Tags: reactjs

Ребята, подскажите, как правильно организовать на React'e такой функционал. Есть два компонента (функциональных) - Main и Setting. Маin собирает несколько компонентов в себе, включая и Setting. Пока в Main включил функционал переключение языков, скорее всего это неправильно все-таки. Setting, в свою очередь, включает в себе switcher (input), который переключает языки app (en/ua). Теперь по коду:

**Main.js**

```
import Setting from '../components/_Setting/Setting';
import { contextArr } from 'App/db'; // перевод словосочетаний app

export default function Main() {
    const location = useLocation();
    let [lang, setLang] = useState('en');

    const chooseLang = (event) => {
        setLang(event.target.checked ? (lang = 'ua') : (lang = 'en'));
    };

    for (let key in contextArr) {
        let elem = document.querySelector('.lng-' + key);
        if (elem) {
            elem.innerHTML = contextArr[key][lang];
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.location.href = location.pathname + '#' + lang;
    }, [location.pathname, lang]);

    return (
        <main id='main'>
            <div className='container df'>
                ...
                <Setting />
              ...
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Setting.js**

```
import Switcher from '../Switcher/Switcher';

export default function Setting() {
return (
        <section id='setting'>
        <Switcher
          id='lang'
          title='Language'
          title_class='lng-set_subtitle1'
          label_lt='English'
          label_rt='Українська'
          value={lang}
          onClick={chooseLang}
        />
        </section>
    );
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

При данном варианте ничего не работает пока. Ранее был функционал переключение языков в компоненте Setting, но в таком случае переключение языков, распространялось только на компонент Setting, а не на весь app.
Просьба не судит строго код, возможно я спросил некорректно, но я думаю функционал (чего я хочу) понятно объяснил.

Comment: Используйте context https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Answer (score 0):

В main.js

```js
<Setting chooseLang={chooseLang} />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

В setting.js

```js
import Switcher from '../Switcher/Switcher';

export default function Setting({ chooseLang }) {
return (
        <section id='setting'>
        <Switcher
          id='lang'
          title='Language'
          title_class='lng-set_subtitle1'
          label_lt='English'
          label_rt='Українська'
          value={lang}
          onClick={chooseLang}
        />
        </section>
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```